# Is there a way to use FORALL to insert data from an array?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql

I am running oracle 19c and I want to get the best insert performance I can. Currently, I insert using `INSERT /*+APPEND */ ...` which is fine, but not the speeds I wanted.
I read that using `FORALL` is a lot faster but I couldn't really find any examples.
here is the code snippet (python 3) :

```py
connection = pool.acquire()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany("INSERT /*+APPEND*/ INTO RANDOM VALUES (:1, :2, :3)", list(random))
connection.commit()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Comment: [`FORALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-optimization-and-tuning.html#GUID-6D4A1425-64DD-4723-8AAE-87B0A51A2854) is part of PL/SQL syntax, not SQL, so you would need a PL/SQL procedure or block, and I don't know how you use those in Python. If you can pass in the array I agree it should be more efficient though. By the way, the [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comments.html#GUID-562DD503-2F99-448E-B044-737BE726B58A) hint does nothing in `insert ... values` - you need `append_values`.

Comment: How large is the list you are inserting?  What sort of performance are you getting?  Are there triggers on the table?  Are there a lot of indexes?  Where is the list coming from?

Comment: @JustinCave The array varies between 100000 to 600000 items, currently I am getting an average of 3.4 seconds per list-insretion

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, I didn't understand what do you mean, I am really new to PL/SQL

Comment: If we take the midpoint and say you're inserting an average of 350,000 items in 3.4 seconds, that's 100,000 items per second.  Your table has three columns.  If we guess each column is a number and that it averages 8 bytes per number, that's 24 bytes per row or 2.3 MB/s.  Assuming you're going over the network from the machine running the Python code to the machine running Oracle, that seems like pretty good performance.  Are you sure that Oracle is the bottleneck here and not your network?

Comment: @JustinCave Yeah I am pretty sure, I am connected by LAN to the DB and it is the same performance when running locally. The main issue is that this is way too slow for me, and I am looking for ways to improve it

Comment: Where does the list come from?  Are there triggers on the table?  Indexes?  What sort of performance are you looking for?

Comment: @JustinCave I generate the list from a different part of the system (0.03 seconds on average), there are no triggers or indexes. I want to insert about 40M entries in two weeks top

Comment: If you're inserting 350,000 items in 3.4 seconds, that would imply that you could insert 40,000,000 items in roughly 390 seconds or about 6.5 minutes.

Comment: @JustinCave Insert 40M items that contains 350,000 rows each

Comment: You should already be taking advantage of batch binding here with the ExecuteMany method. Have you tried to see what happens with the fixed hint - `insert_values`? That said, your 40M rows in two weeks requirement seems like it’s already easily satisfied at your current rate of 100K rows a second.

Comment: Otherwise, keep it as a non-direct path insert and scale out your python processes so each takes a chunk of your items and inserts those independently. So long as you don’t have any difficult indexing, and you have sufficient processing power on the database server, it will have no trouble increasing performance linearly with number of client processes.

Comment: @AndrewSayer, as I said, it is 40M items which contain 350,000 rows each. What is `insert_values`?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `append_values`, it is a hint which allows you to do direct path insert when you use the insert..values statement like you are doing.

Comment: *"40M items that contains 350,000 rows each"* What generates these 40m items? Oracle offers built-in capabilities for bulk loading. These are generally far more efficient than our hand-rolled utilities. If you explain more about your scenario we might be able to offer an alternative approach.

Comment: @APC I am just responsible for the DB, so as far as I know, there is some sort of engine that generates these items and needs to store them in a DB. Not really sure why or how

Answer (score 2):

I really get interested in what would be faster, so I've tested some possibile ways to compare them:

- simple `executemany` with no tricks.
- the same with `APPEND_VALUES` hint inside the statement.
- `union all` approach you've tried in another question. This should be slower than above since it generates a **really very large** statement (that potentially can require more network than the data itself). It then should be parsed at DB side that will also consume a lot of time and neglect all the benefits (not talking about potential size limit). Then I've `executemany`'ed it to test with chunks not to build a single statement for 100k records. I didn't use concatenation of values inside the statement, because wanted to keep it safe.
- [`insert all`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9014.htm#i2121682). The same downsides, but no unions. Compare it with the `union` version.
- serialize the data in JSON and do deserialization at DB side with [`json_table`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions092.htm#SQLRF56973). Potentially good performance with single short statement and single data transfer with little overhead of JSON.
- Your suggested [`FORALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm#LNPLS01321) in PL/SQL wrapper procedure. Should be the same as `executemany` since does the same, but at the database side. Overhead of transformation of the data into the collection.
- The same `FORALL`, but with columnar approach to pass the data: pass simple lists of column values instead of complex type. Should be much faster than `FORALL` with collection since there's no need to serialize the data into collection's type.

I've used Oracle Autonomous Database in Oracle Cloud with free account. Each method was executed for 10 times in loop with the same input dataset of 100k records, table was recreated before each test. This is the result I've got. Preparation and execution times here are data transformation at client side end DB call itself respectively.

```
>>> t = PerfTest(100000)
>>> t.run("exec_many", 10)
Method:  exec_many.
    Duration, avg: 2.3083874 s
    Preparation time, avg: 0.0 s
    Execution time, avg: 2.3083874 s
>>> t.run("exec_many_append", 10)
Method: exec_many_append.
    Duration, avg: 2.6031369 s
    Preparation time, avg: 0.0 s
    Execution time, avg: 2.6031369 s
>>> t.run("union_all", 10, 10000)
Method:  union_all.
    Duration, avg: 27.9444233 s
    Preparation time, avg: 0.0408773 s
    Execution time, avg: 27.8457551 s
>>> t.run("insert_all", 10, 10000)
Method: insert_all.
    Duration, avg: 70.6442494 s
    Preparation time, avg: 0.0289269 s
    Execution time, avg: 70.5541995 s
>>> t.run("json_table", 10)
Method: json_table.
    Duration, avg: 10.4648237 s
    Preparation time, avg: 9.7907693 s
    Execution time, avg: 0.621006 s
>>> t.run("forall", 10)
Method:     forall.
    Duration, avg: 5.5622837 s
    Preparation time, avg: 1.8972456000000002 s
    Execution time, avg: 3.6650380999999994 s
>>> t.run("forall_columnar", 10)
Method: forall_columnar.
    Duration, avg: 2.6702698000000002 s
    Preparation time, avg: 0.055710800000000005 s
    Execution time, avg: 2.6105702 s
>>>
```

The fastest way is just `executemany`, not so much surprise. Interesting here is that `APPEND_VALUES` does not improve the query and gets more time on average, so this needs more investigation.

About `FORALL`: as expected, individual array for each column takes less time as there's no data preparation for it. It is more or less comparable with `executemany`, but I think PL/SQL overhead plays some role here.

Another interesting part for me is JSON: most of the time was spent on writing LOB into database and serialization, but the query itself was very fast. Maybe write operation can be improved in some way with chuncsize or some another way to pass LOB data into select statement, but as of my code it is far from very simple and straightforward approach with `executemany`.

There`re also possible approaches without Python that *should* be faster as native tools for external data, but I didn't tested them:

- [Oracle SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html)
- [External table](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-external-tables.html)

Below is the code I've used for testing.

```
import cx_Oracle as db
import os, random, json
import datetime as dt


class PerfTest:
  
  def __init__(self, size):
    self._con = db.connect(
      os.environ["ora_cloud_usr"],
      os.environ["ora_cloud_pwd"],
      "test_low",
      encoding="UTF-8"
    )
    self._cur = self._con.cursor()
    self.inp = [(i, "Test {i}".format(i=i), random.random()) for i in range(size)]
  
  def __del__(self):
    if self._con:
      self._con.rollback()
      self._con.close()
 
#Create objets
  def setup(self):
    try:
      self._cur.execute("drop table rand")
      #print("table dropped")
    except:
      pass
  
    self._cur.execute("""create table rand(
      id int,
      str varchar2(100),
      val number
    )""")
    
    self._cur.execute("""create or replace package pkg_test as
  type ts_test is record (
    id rand.id%type,
    str rand.str%type,
    val rand.val%type
  );
  type tt_test is table of ts_test index by pls_integer;
  
  type tt_ids is table of rand.id%type index by pls_integer;
  type tt_strs is table of rand.str%type index by pls_integer;
  type tt_vals is table of rand.val%type index by pls_integer;
  
  procedure write_data(p_data in tt_test);
  procedure write_data_columnar(
    p_ids in tt_ids,
    p_strs in tt_strs,
    p_vals in tt_vals
  );

end;""")
    self._cur.execute("""create or replace package body pkg_test as
  procedure write_data(p_data in tt_test)
  as
  begin
    forall i in indices of p_data
      insert into rand(id, str, val)
      values (p_data(i).id, p_data(i).str, p_data(i).val)
    ;
    
    commit;

  end;
  
  procedure write_data_columnar(
    p_ids in tt_ids,
    p_strs in tt_strs,
    p_vals in tt_vals
  ) as
  begin
    forall i in indices of p_ids
      insert into rand(id, str, val)
      values (p_ids(i), p_strs(i), p_vals(i))
    ;
    
    commit;
    
  end;

end;
""")

 
  def build_union(self, size):
      return """insert into rand(id, str, val)
    select id, str, val from rand where 1 = 0 union all
    """ + """ union all """.join(
      ["select :{}, :{}, :{} from dual".format(i*3+1, i*3+2, i*3+3)
        for i in range(size)]
    )
 
 
  def build_insert_all(self, size):
      return """
      """.join(
      ["into rand(id, str, val) values (:{}, :{}, :{})".format(i*3+1, i*3+2, i*3+3)
        for i in range(size)]
    )


#Test case with executemany
  def exec_many(self):
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.executemany("insert into rand(id, str, val) values (:1, :2, :3)", self.inp)
    self._con.commit()
    
    return (dt.timedelta(0), dt.datetime.now() - start)
 
 
#The same as above but with prepared statement (no parsing)
  def exec_many_append(self):
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.executemany("insert /*+APPEND_VALUES*/ into rand(id, str, val) values (:1, :2, :3)", self.inp)
    self._con.commit()
    
    return (dt.timedelta(0), dt.datetime.now() - start)


#Union All approach (chunked). Should have large parse time
  def union_all(self, size):
##Chunked list of big tuples
    start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
    new_inp = [
      tuple([item for t in r for item in t])
      for r in list(zip(*[iter(self.inp)]*size))
    ]
    new_stmt = self.build_union(size)
    
    dur_prepare = dt.datetime.now() - start_prepare
    
    #Execute unions
    start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.executemany(new_stmt, new_inp)
    dur_exec = dt.datetime.now() - start_exec

##In case the size is not a divisor
    remainder = len(self.inp) % size
    if remainder > 0 :
      start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
      new_stmt = self.build_union(remainder)
      new_inp = tuple([
        item for t in self.inp[-remainder:] for item in t
      ])
      dur_prepare += dt.datetime.now() - start_prepare
      
      start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
      self._cur.execute(new_stmt, new_inp)
      dur_exec += dt.datetime.now() - start_exec

    self._con.commit()
    
    return (dur_prepare, dur_exec)


#The same as union all, but with no need to union something
  def insert_all(self, size):
##Chunked list of big tuples
    start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
    new_inp = [
      tuple([item for t in r for item in t])
      for r in list(zip(*[iter(self.inp)]*size))
    ]
    new_stmt = """insert all
    {}
    select * from dual"""
    dur_prepare = dt.datetime.now() - start_prepare
    
    #Execute
    start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.executemany(
      new_stmt.format(self.build_insert_all(size)),
      new_inp
    )
    dur_exec = dt.datetime.now() - start_exec

##In case the size is not a divisor
    remainder = len(self.inp) % size
    if remainder > 0 :
      start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
      new_inp = tuple([
        item for t in self.inp[-remainder:] for item in t
      ])
      dur_prepare += dt.datetime.now() - start_prepare
      
      start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
      self._cur.execute(
        new_stmt.format(self.build_insert_all(remainder)),
        new_inp
      )
      dur_exec += dt.datetime.now() - start_exec

    self._con.commit()
    
    return (dur_prepare, dur_exec)

    
#Serialize at server side and do deserialization at DB side
  def json_table(self):
    start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
    new_inp = json.dumps([
      { "id":t[0], "str":t[1], "val":t[2]} for t in self.inp
    ])
    
    lob_var = self._con.createlob(db.DB_TYPE_CLOB)
    lob_var.write(new_inp)
    
    start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.execute("""
    insert into rand(id, str, val)
    select id, str, val
    from json_table(
      to_clob(:json), '$[*]'
      columns
        id int,
        str varchar2(100),
        val number
    )
    """, json=lob_var)
    dur_exec = dt.datetime.now() - start_exec
    
    self._con.commit()
    
    return (start_exec - start_prepare, dur_exec)


#PL/SQL with FORALL
  def forall(self):
    start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
    collection_type = self._con.gettype("PKG_TEST.TT_TEST")
    record_type = self._con.gettype("PKG_TEST.TS_TEST")
    
    def recBuilder(x):
      rec = record_type.newobject()
      rec.ID = x[0]
      rec.STR = x[1]
      rec.VAL = x[2]
      
      return rec

    inp_collection = collection_type.newobject([
      recBuilder(i) for i in self.inp
    ])
    
    start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.callproc("pkg_test.write_data", [inp_collection])
    dur_exec = dt.datetime.now() - start_exec
    
    return (start_exec - start_prepare, dur_exec)


#PL/SQL with FORALL and plain collections
  def forall_columnar(self):
    start_prepare = dt.datetime.now()
    ids, strs, vals = map(list, zip(*self.inp))
    start_exec = dt.datetime.now()
    self._cur.callproc("pkg_test.write_data_columnar", [ids, strs, vals])
    dur_exec = dt.datetime.now() - start_exec
    
    return (start_exec - start_prepare, dur_exec)

  
#Run test
  def run(self, method, iterations, *args):
    #Cleanup schema
    self.setup()

    start = dt.datetime.now()
    runtime = []
    for i in range(iterations):
      single_run = getattr(self, method)(*args)
      runtime.append(single_run)
    
    dur = dt.datetime.now() - start
    dur_prep_total = sum([i.total_seconds() for i, _ in runtime])
    dur_exec_total = sum([i.total_seconds() for _, i in runtime])
    
    print("""Method: {meth}.
    Duration, avg: {run_dur} s
    Preparation time, avg: {prep} s
    Execution time, avg: {ex} s""".format(
      inp_s=len(self.inp),
      meth=method,
      run_dur=dur.total_seconds() / iterations,
      prep=dur_prep_total / iterations,
      ex=dur_exec_total / iterations
    ))
```

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you very much!