# Is there a way to automate UNION ALL insertion?

Tags: python, oracle

I am using an oracle 19c, and I am trying to insert using the union all method. I tried to automate it and I am getting ORA-00907.
Here is my code:

```py
def insert(items):
    # items is a list of dicts -> 
    # [{"test": "Test", "Test": "test", "r": "a"}, {"test": "Test", "Test": "test", "s": "a"}...]
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    insertions = []
    for item in items:
        insertions.append(item["test"], item["Test"])  
    query = """INSERT INTO C##USER.RANDOM
SELECT (:1, :2) FROM dual
""" + "\n".join(["UNION ALL SELECT (:{i}, {i+1}) FROM dual" for i in range(3, len(insertions), 2)])
    cursor.execute(query, insertions)
```

Comment: What is the actual SQL generated by your code?

Comment: No idea, I have no way to check this with cx_Oracle as far as I know

Comment: Probably related [to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66622722/146325)

Comment: If your goal (based on your other question) is to improve performance, generating millions of statements each with hundreds of thousands of `union all` statements that the database would have to hard parse each time is very, very unlikely to be beneficial.

Comment: Well, you **have** a possibility to check **your statement** simple by `print (query)`, you will see immediately that you generate `UNION ALL SELECT (:{i}, {i+1}) FROM dual` but what you probably wants is `UNION ALL SELECT (:3, :4) FROM dual`

Comment: Why do you put parentheses aroud values in `select`? Oracle [does not allow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) you to do so, because `(<some_value>, <some_value>)` is not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [executemany](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#batch-execution-of-sql) is the better option for your use case.

example from the page:

```
dataToInsert = [
    (10, 'Parent 10'),
    (20, 'Parent 20'),
    (30, 'Parent 30'),
    (40, 'Parent 40'),
    (50, 'Parent 50')
]
cursor.executemany("insert into ParentTable values (:1, :2)", dataToInsert)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a better option? I tried executemany and it was too slow for me

Comment: Looking at your other post linked by @APC, why don't you use [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-sql-loader.html#GUID-8D037494-07FA-4226-B507-E1B2ED10C144)?

Comment: I didn't know it existed, is it possible to use it in python?

Comment: You call it as system command using `os.system`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to effectively insert a large number of generated *test* data,

you **should neither** use

```
INSERT /*+APPEND*/ INTO ... VALUES (...)
```

As in the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66622722/4808122) question.

Note that you are inserting *row by row* so the `APPEND`hint is *meaningless* here and is ignored.

**neither** you should use as large `UNION ALL` select and bind *thousands of bind variables*.

As pointed by others this will take a large parsing time.

You **should approach** this with *one* `INSERT` statement that process all rows to be inserted:

Example

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into tab (col1,col2)
select rownum, 'Test'||rownum from dual 
connect by level <= 10000;
```

Note this will populate your table with 10000 rows such as

```
      COL1 COL2                                        
---------- --------------------------------------------
         1 Test1                                       
         2 Test2                                       
         3 Test3                                       
         4 Test4                                       
         5 Test5 
....
```

Comment: Thank you! But `Test` was just an example, each row is completely different from the last, and I cannot just generate it like this